# D7 | views filter to show current user nodes or all nodes if admin

Tags: views, nodes, users

I have a site with multiple roles:
admin
editor1
editor2
editor3
…

I would like to be able to show a node reference drop down menu to only show current users's nodes. So each user can only node-ref to other nodes that they authored.

BUT if the user is an admin, they need to see the entire nodes list.

I thought this could be done with some views filters.
Using user:current as a filter does part of this requirement... but changing that list based on if the current user is as admin role is the part I don't know how to do.

Any ideas?

thx in advance

Comment: Did you solve this problem, I have the same issue. Maybe we should alter views by views hooks? also there is a module for D6: http://drupal.org/project/views_or

Comment: @Mohammad Ali Akbari : I eventually ended up using a workaround, using the Rules module to autotag content by its username value and the administrator value and then filtered on this tag in views. I wouldn't call it a optimal solution though. View Or would be a big help here.